# Java 11 weakCAS implementation

Tags: java, jvm

Is AtomicInteger.compareAndSet the still same as AtomicInteger.weakCompareAndSetVolatile and AtomicInteger.weakCompareAndSetPlain in Java 11?

In Java 8 these methods just called the same method with same parameters.

Since Java 9 they call different methods from VarHandle but it seems to me that those methods are identical.

So I wonder if weakCompareAndSet is still not implemented properly despite the fact that it can be used in many concurrent algorithms to optimize them.

Comment: What do you mean by "not implemented properly"? What is a proper implementation?

Comment: A proper implementation is an implementation which is different than just using simple CAS in weakCAS. A proper weakCAS implementation should not perform some check that CAS does because it is allowed not to perform them.

Comment: Your question comes from a wrong assumption that weak CAS should somehow differ from strong CAS. This is not necessarily true.

It *may* be different on *some* architectures, for instance, on ARM, which does not have a hardware compare-and-exchange instruction, but this is not actual for x86-64 which has strong `cmpxchg` in hardware.